# How can I make a dynamic array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Quick overview of our assignment:
User needs to enter grades received. We do not know how many grades user needs to enter. If the user enters "-1" thats when we know the user is done entering grades.

Problem is how do you use a counter and assign values to an array in the same loop? I would rather not have to ask the user to enter all values twice (Once to get array size and the second time to assign grades to index positions).

Our professor gave us a handout that tells us to basically guess the size of the array and hope for the best. I refuse to believe that's the only solution.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For your case, it is better to use data structure like LinkedList.

Comment: @fajarkoe Really just a `List/ArrayList` :|

Comment: If you can't use List (for whatever terrible reason - e.g. school assignment xD), consider creating an array *larger* than number of values that can be entered (memory is pretty darn cheap), and possibly a count of how many values have been entered: this avoids having to deal with resizing (or, creating a new array and copying) or re-iterating the [user] input.

Comment: @user2864740 If you use LinkedList, you don't have to worry about having to enlarge the backing array as in ArrayList.

Comment: @fajarkoe If I use an ArrayList, I don't have to worry about the backing array either .. and the performance overhead of the occasional backing array resize is fairly well amortized. A LinkedList also has additional fixed per-element overhead and increased allocation requirements. (That is, except in cases where I *know* and can/care to *show* that a LinkedList was a better implementation, where such even matters, I use an ArrayList.)

Comment: @user2864740 You have to worry about the backing array in the sense that it will have performance impact to your code. I understand that we don't have to manually enlarging the backing array ourselves.

Comment: @fajarkoe This "performance impact" that is spoken of simply does not apply. An ArrayList is O(1) *amortized* append.

Comment: @user2864740 Correct, ArrayList has constant-time amortized time for insertion operation. But, this is amortized time. In contrast, LinkedList has constant time for insertion operation. In OP's case, only insertions are performed. So, LinkedList is a better choice in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some kind of `List` is a better choice, as it basically does what you want (can grow and shrink), in fact, `ArrayList` is just that, a dynamic array.

You can hand roll your own if you can't use a `List` using [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

For example, this will grow or shrink an array to match the size you provide...

```
public String[] updateArray(String[] src, int size) {

    String[] dest = new String[size];
    if (size > src.length) {

        System.arraycopy(src, 0, dest, 0, src.length);

    } else {

        System.arraycopy(src, 0, dest, 0, size);

    }

    return dest;

}
```

Again... `List` is easier...

Answer (score 2):

You can't make dynamic array in java.

For that you will have to use `List` or `ArrayList`.

We will have to provide the size of array before application run or at coding time, while arrayList gives us facility to add data while we need it, so it's size will automatically increased when we add data.

Example :

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListDemo {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      // create an array list
      ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
      System.out.println("Initial size of al: " + al.size());

      // add elements to the array list
      al.add("C");
      al.add("A");
      al.add("E");
      al.add("B");
      al.add("D");
      al.add("F");
      al.add(1, "A2");
      System.out.println("Size of al after additions: " + al.size());

      // display the array list
      System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);
      // Remove elements from the array list
      al.remove("F");
      al.remove(2);
      System.out.println("Size of al after deletions: " + al.size());
      System.out.println("Contents of al: " + al);
   }
}
```

this example is from [here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm)

UPDATE :

When you define your list as:

`List myList = new ArrayList();`
you can only call methods and reference members that belong to List class. If you define it as:

`ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();`
you'll be able to invoke ArrayList specific methods and use ArrayList specific members in addition to those inherited from List.

**List is not a class it is an interface. It doesn't have any methods implemented. So if you call a method on a List reference, you in fact calling the method of ArrayList in both cases.**

Comment: Yes exactly.It's something like `List<String> l = new ArrayList...`

Comment: Could you clarify it in your answer? Specially the part *"you will have to use `List` or `ArrayList`"*. For a newbie it can be misunderstood, like if those were totally different types of dynamic arrays.

Comment: *"You can't make dynamic array in java"* - Yes you can, the question is, why would you.  `ArrayList` is just that, a dynamic array, a `List` backed by an array ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Yes exactly that ArrayList is Dynamic Array.

Comment: Best practice is List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>;

Comment: @dikkini it's `List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @dikkini : it's `List<String> s = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys! While I did learn a lot about arrays and lists thanks to all of your help, I found out the easiest thing to do is just make variables for A, B, C, etc (For the grades) and use them each as a counter

Answer (score 0):

Building a dynamic array involves these basic steps:

-Create an array of a fixed capacity.

-When the size of the array (# of elements added) approach the capacity, create a new array (usually doubling the capacity), and copy all the old elements to the new array.

A linked list is the most efficient for your task of building the array (done in O(1) time). However, accessing elements for inserting and deleting in a linked list is not efficient (O(n) time). Imagine having to move through the whole list to get to the last element. Building the dynamic array is less efficient, because of the need to re-size the array as it grows. Inserting and deleting elements is less efficient because of need to move all the elements after to make room or fill the gap. However accessing an element in an array is efficient (O(1) time) and there are big advantages when it comes to sorting.

The Java ArrayList is an implementation of a dynamic array. You could also implement your own.

Comment: And I believe the question was how to MAKE a dynamic array, not what Java library can I use for this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use an ArrayList, or any kind of dynamic list at all, then one solution would be this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int j;
while((j=scanner.nextInt()) !=-1){
    sb.append(j + " ");
}
String []numbers = sb.toString().split(" ");
int[] grades = new int[numbers.length];
for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    grades[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
}
```

As you can see, I'm putting the input in a stringbuilder object, then I parse it in an array of strings, and convert that array in an integer array.
I hope this helps.